# Power series for square root of rank-1 perturbation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, taylor-expansion

I know from [power series for square root matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884812/power-series-for-square-root-matrix) that $U=(I+A)^{1/2}$ can be expanded to power series provided $||A||<1$.
How can I expand  $(B+A)^{1/2}$ when $B$ is Hermitian (edited) positive definite and $A=\bf{u}\bf{u}^H$ is a rank-1 perturbation (modification). That is, $\bf{u}$ is a vector. What is the condition for convergence?

The equivalent trick for $U=(B+A)^{-1}$, where $B$ is taken out, seems not to work in the case of square root.

Comment: Are we given that $B$ is positive semidefinitie? If not, then what exactly do you mean by $(B+A)^{1/2}$?

Comment: If I may ask, why are vectors in bold when matrices are not?